# JUnit testing custom Eclipse builders

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created an extra builder for Java projects.

I'm trying to test it automatically via JUnit test that changes and refreshes a project file and expects automatic builder to kick in. Unfortunately this doesn't happen.

I can access and modify Workspace from that test but I don't know how to deal with builders (or GUI elements). I also tried to check "Run in UI thread" in junit test's debug configuration but no success.

What's the proper way to do this kind of testing? (I'd like to avoid learning TPTP, if possible -- looks too heavy).

How to initiate "Project -> Clean" command from my tests? Or how to execute any UI command? I suppose there are some threading issues to take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the command:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD, null);
```

and 
    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.CLEAN_BUILD, null);

The first will initiate a clean, and then a build on the entire workspace.  The second will initiate only a clean.

Alternatively, if you have access to an `IProject` object, you can call `build` on that.

Comment: I tried <code>build</code> method on <code>IProject</code> but my builder was not invoked.

Comment: Are you sure that the builder is installed in your project?  Try IProject.getDescription().getBuildSpec().  Make sure that your builder is in that array.

Comment: Oh noes, the builder is not there! :)  My own (buggy) configuration GUI said that builder is installed, but actually only nature was installed :D  Thanks a lot!!